# What computer science topic am I trying to describe?

Tags: computer-science

I've been programming for around... 6->8 years, and I've begun to realize that I don't really know what really happens at the low-ish level when I do something like

```
int i = j%348
```

The thing is, I know what j%348 does, it divides j by 348 and finds the remainder.  What I don't know is HOW the computer does this.

Similarly, I know that

```
try
{
 blah();
}catch(Exception e){
 blah2();
}
```

will invoke `blah` and if blah throws, it will invoke `blah2`... however, I have no idea how the computer does this instead of err... crashing or ending execution.

And I figure that in order for me to get "better" at programming, I should probably know what my code is really doing.  [This would probably also help me optimize and... err... not do stupid things]

I figure that what I'm asking for is probably something huge taught in universities or something, but to be honest, if I could learn a little, I would be happy.

The point of the question is:
**What topic/computer-science-course am I asking about?**  Because in all honesty, I don't know.

Since I don't know what the topic is called, I'm unable to actually find a book or online resource to learn about the topic, so I'm sort of stuck.  I'd be eternally thankful if someone helped me =/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should  **look into assembly first**, and **then get into compiler design**. If you don't know assembly you'll be completely lost with compiler design. I'm personally just starting with assembly, for the exact reason you are - I want to understand what my code is doing at a lower level.

I found this resource, which is very cool: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly

Basically it's an assembly book that explains some of the concepts of how higher level code is executed in assembly, and has some examples where it shows how functions etc might be generated in assembly by a compiler.

Comment: +1 for assembly, It definitively helps you to give insight about what happens 'behind' all those nifty syntactic sugar your language is providing you.

Comment: I have decided that I will follow what you have suggested.  I will learn assembly, and after that, I will get into compiler design.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Update: A few months into this and it's going pretty well.  Writing a simple interpreter for a simple language.  Not writing a compiler yet, but hopefully i'll be doing that in the next year or so.

Comment: @ItzWarty: Cool! Thanks for the followup. So what route did you decide to follow? Have you looked into assembly, or have you concentrated on lexing/parsing? What resources did you use, etc? :)

Comment: Both =P.  So now, i'm working on a program to parse a script into a parsetree, which will then we walked/executed...  Before that, I learned to work with nasm and some Z80-like asm [gameboy]...  Pretty interesting.  The interpreter is written in c#, and it's just parsing javascript-like syntax.  Has a ton of optimization to go, but i've parsed hello world in 0.0002 seconds >_>[it's only 1 line, JS-like, once again]

Comment: @ItzWarty: So how did your project go :)? I've since taken compilers and computer architecture at university. It's really interesting stuff. We used MIPS for assembly, which I found to be a great learning language do to its simplicity. Also I bought the purple dragon book which has been really interesting. It feels beginner-friendly and reasonably comprehensive at the same time.

Comment: @Cam: Let's say I got the processor working, and then got bored after that, and deviated into many other projects.  I eventually started the RAF Manager project, which allowed users to modify the game League of Legends, which was downloaded hundreds of thousands of times.  The understanding of lower level constructs has really helped me understand and apply stuff.  After or around the time that I wrote the topic, I also passed the test to skip into the AP comp sci course at my school, which was a breeze.  Now taking Adv Topics, and we actually did some stuff in 6502 assembly.  Was easy for me!

Comment: @Cam: For the RAF Manager project, there's actually interpreted scripts for installing mods.  I started the project to allow colorblind users to install modifications that would make their gameplay nicer, and used scripting to present users with configuration windows, and to modify the game based on the user's preference.  My high school's giving a course on Compilers and Interpreters next year (will be a senior!), so that'll be really fun.  I also went on to become the leader of the software development team at my school's robotics club, which has been pretty cool.

Comment: @Cam: Also, in general, I've come to really appreciate what languages like c# and JavaScript let you do.  It's pretty common for me to call languages "beautiful" after learning about all this lower level stuff.  I've also used the knowledge to begin my next project, which involves patching memory in order to redirect the League of Legends game, to redirect file reads and such.  Essentially, learning lower level stuff opened a ton of avenues for me, which has been really really awesome.  Apparently writing a 1-page post can keep you occupied for a long time, haha!

Comment: @Cam: Also, my dad (the dude with the dragon book) used to go to the University of Waterloo, haha.  Anyways, thanks to you (and everyone else) who gave advice in this thread.  It was extremely helpful in my understanding of Computer Science in general.

Answer (score 12):

I would say the first part is computer architecture, while the second part is programming language.

Some good books on computer architecture, if you are interested in understanding a bit more on how the computer executes a program are:

- [The Elements of Computing Systems: Building a Modern Computer from First Principles](http://www1.idc.ac.il/tecs/),
  By Noam Nisan and Shimon Schocken
- [Structured Computer Organization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131485210), by Andrew Tanenbaum

I'm not sure what to recommend for understanding programming language constructs such as catching exceptions. Probably a good compilers book.

Especially with your second example, different programming languages might be implemented very differently. For example, a language running on a virtual machine such as Java, would have the virtual machine to protect it and throw certain types of exceptions, while in C++ this would be handled differently.

Comment: +1 for The Elements of Computing Systems. That book is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

The first part might be considered computer engineering, but the second is just language design.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at how a compiler translates a high-level language code to machine instructions. Have a look at compiler design. This is a classic [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design).

Comment: WOAH! I recognize the cover! I know my dad has that book!  When I was a kid I used to look at the book's cover and think it was a fairy tale book ._.

Comment: @Itz - +1 for having thought the dragon book was a fairytale :)

Comment: @Itz +1 for having a dad who has the dragon book.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds vaguely like you're talking about compiler construction and language design.

The (most) general "CS thing" that can implement exceptions is probably continuations (as found in, among other things, Scheme). If you haven't read thouhg "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" (SICP, [Web page here, including full text](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)) it may be worth giving a quick go-through, it touches lightly on compiler construction.

Answer (score 0):

The actual mechanism used to calculate the modulus is likely to vary between languages and  then between the implementation of each language. There some information about the algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Maybe Algorithms is the general area you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

No one is talking about Mathematic for modulo?
First semester for media informatics (I'm in the fifth), course: Mathematic:

10 % 3 = ?
x % y = z

Calculation:

1. 10 / 3 = 3.33333
2. 3.3333 rounded to 3
3. 3 * 3 = 9
4. 10 - 9 = 1

As one formular:
10 - (Math.round(10 / 3) * 3) = 1

With variables:
x % y = x - (Math.round(x / y) * y)

Understanding binary and you will understand, that each math operation is based on addition.

Answer (score 0):

The book mentioned above, "The Elements of Computing Systems: Building a Modern Computer from First Principles", By Noam Nisan and Shimon Schocken, addresses the types of questions that you raise in a holistic way: from architecture to VM to compilers to OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to spend any money, there's a great book called "Computer Organization and Design Fundamentals" available [here](http://www.lulu.com/content/content_download_redirect.php?contentId=138292&version=3) (PDF link). I also recommend "Code" by Charles Petzold, published by Microsoft Press.